# Improving convergence with compactness criterion

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $x_n \to x$ in $(X, \tau)$. Let $\tau' \supseteq \tau$ be a finer topology such that $\{ x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is relatively compact for $\tau'$. Does it follow that $x_n \to x$ in $(X, \tau')$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Shouldn’t $x$ be added to the set?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Even when forcing relative compactness?

Comment: If $x$ is not in the set it cannot be compact in $\tau$ let alone in $\tau'$. So the assumption forces $x \in \{x_n : n \in \Bbb N\}$. But I think it should be explicit I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $\{ x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ relatively compact for $\tau'$ means that closure of this set in $(X, \tau')$ is $\tau'$-compact or equivalently, that $\{ x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is contained in some $\tau'$-compact subset of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true. There is a subnet of $(x_n)$ converging to some point $y$ w.r.t. $\tau'$. This subnet also converges to $y$ w.r.t. $\tau$. Since $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff we get $x=y$. No we can repeat this with any subnet of $(x_n)$ to see that every subnet has  further subnet converging to $x$. This implies $x_n \to x$ in $\tau'$.

Comment: Thank you. An interesting alternative approach to circumvent relative sequential compactness of $\{ x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.